# How can I prevent my layout from disrupting when a Javascript function runs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I've just added a Javascript function of changeText to make my site have the accessibility feature of making text larger in order for visually impaired users to be able to use my site with more ease. However upon clicking on the icon for 'larger text' which runs the javascript, it messes up my layout. How can I correct this? Would it be CSS? Here is the website:

[www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate][1]

and the enlarge text icons are to the right hand side of the header. Or if this helps, this is the code:

```
<div id="font-size-buttons">
   <a href="#" onclick="changeText(100)"><img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/images2/fontmin.png" width="25" height"25" alt="Switch to original text size and colours"></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="changeText(150)"><img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/images2/fontmax.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Switch to larger text and improved colour contrast"></a>
  </div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function changeText(size) {
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
obj.style.fontSize = size + '%';
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't visually impaired persons use the zoom feature of their browser? Zoom avoids most of the layout problems that you noted.

Comment: yes but this is for a university brief and so we have to cater for people using screens such as a mobile phone which may not have a zoom function for example. annoying but what we have to do!

Comment: Then I recommend live editing using the Chrome browser. Via the developer panel, it allows you to emulate various mobile devices and also edit the CSS.  This is a much easier and faster way to see what works and what doesn't.  Then you incorporate those working changes into the actual css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `div#font-size-buttons` is inheriting your new `font-size:150%` rule, which pumps up its height to 48px after click.
To combat this you need to fix it height to let's say 32px, as so:

```
#font-size-buttons {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

You'll need these too:

```
.intro {
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.subgroup1 {
  width: 64.54%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

(I removed fixed height from .subgroup and decreased margin, to make div more "elastic")

```
#footer {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial, palatino sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #A3CC39;
  clear: both;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

(Again - removed `height:20px` from footer to make div adjusts itself)

Comment: fab that helped solve one part of the problem thank you! do you know how I can solve the bottom half of my page layout disrupting?

Comment: Your main problems there are fixed heights on elements - your containers are not flexible enough to accomodate changes to their content. See my edits - give it a go and let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website yes you need to add css to it to draw your website and limit part of the website so the js does not affect things you dont want to.

but you would need to provide more code of your website so we can help you

Comment: Would you be able to use inspect element to see my code? Because its very long to paste in! :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked quickly and changing you whole css would be too long so the workaround I suggest is that your + and - only change your wrapper div as this is your main content. For this change in your js to be

```
<script src="accessjava.js">
function changeText(size) {
var obj = document.getElementsById('wrapper')[0];
obj.style.fontSize = size + '%';
}
</script>
```

and in the body change

```
<div class="wrapper">
```

to be

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

The last thing will be in your css to replace .wrapper by #wrapper to keep the same style you created.
Hope this will help